# NuGet package with EDMX generates files

Tags: entity-framework, nuget

I have a data access project that includes an .edmx with templates and so on. Now, when I add this project as a nuget package and then fetch/update it in another project the database model files are created from the template. This is not really what I want.

Is there something wrong with my design in all this or can I disable this behaviour?

I just need to delete the generated files and everything works fine, but it's mighty annyoing.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Maybe you have to stop build action for this file ?

Comment: @SashaFencyk It only happens once when I add or update the nuget package. Any building after that are fine and no files are generated. The edmx file has a special build action called EntityDeploy, which I suppose could be the cause of this but I think I still need this for the project containing the edmx.

Comment: @JuhaKangas I know this is... almost 10 years later, but did you find a solution to this?